# Inserting image in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How can I insert an image in a scroll view, so that I can zoom it.
I am new to objective c.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add following delegate method of scrollview in your *.m file.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
}
```

Ok. Let me explain in deep.

- open your yourViewCtr.h file.
- Place following two statements in yourViewCtr.h ( here yourViewCtr is assumed your view controller )

`IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrForImg;`
`IBOutlet UIImageView *imgForScr;`

- Save yourViewCtr.h file & open yourViewCtr.xib file.
- Drag & drop UIScrollView in your view controller's view from Interface builder library
- Now, drag & drop UIImageView in that scroll view from Interface Builder library
- Now, Connect both of them to files owner of xib.
- Don't forget to connect the scrollview's delegate to files owner
- Now, Set Max zoom to 5 ( according to your need )
- Save yourViewCtr.xib

`-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{`
`return imgForScr;`
`}`

Hope, It works for you dear.
Add comment if any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your step by step answering. I used the above code. Everything worked fine, but the image is not zooming. How can I zoom it.

Comment: you might have placed a scroll view in interface builder *.xib file. Now, press command + 2 for connections & connect scroll view's delegate to files owner.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ImageKit. In particular, IKImageView. Theoretically, you can put that into your scrollview. I've been playing with this recently...

Granted, I only work in OSX, not iPhone, so your experiences may vary... I'm not sure that IKImageView exists for iPhone, but ImageKit seems to...